# Find the last updated value in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to figure out how to find the last updated value in a table, even though there are multiple dates, example data:

```
entry date | Product | Stock
2021-01-04 | Apple.  | 234
2021-01-03 | Apple.  | 234
2021-01-02 | Apple.  | 234
2021-01-01 | Apple.  | 235
```

The below data set shows that the last time the stock value was updated was on 2021-01-02

I have tried to use a self join and a where not exists statement but the issue i have is the date is the entry date is inserted each day so i cant use max date.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT MIN(entry_date), Product, Stock
  FROM (SELECT entry_date, Product, Stock,
               RANK() OVER(ORDER BY entry_date) RN1,
               RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Stock ORDER BY entry_date) RN2
          FROM YOUR_TABLE)
 WHERE RN1-RN2 <> 0
 GROUP BY Product, Stock;
```